# Could someone explain the method of making rules for connect 4 game in C?

Tags: c

Please explain why 3 needs to be subtracted from `sizewidth` and `sizeheight` variables while defining the rules for connect 4 game in c

```
int checkResult()
{
  int i, j, k, count;

  //checks horizontal win
  for (i = 0; i < sizeWidth; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < sizeHeight - 3; j++)
      if (board[i][j] != 0 && board[i][j] == board[i][j + 1] && board[i][j] == board[i][j + 2] && board[i][j] == board[i][j + 3])
        printf("\n1");
  //return 1;

  //checks vertical win
  for (i = 0; i < sizeWidth - 3; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < sizeHeight; j++)
      if (board[i][j] != 0 && board[i][j] == board[i + 1][j] && board[i][j] == board[i + 2][j] && board[i][j] == board[i + 3][j])
        printf("\n2");
  //return 2;

  //checks rigth diagonal win
  for (i = 0; i < sizeWidth - 3; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < sizeHeight - 3; j++)
      if (board[i][j] != 0 && board[i][j] == board[i + 1][j + 1] && board[i][j] == board[i + 2][j + 2] && board[i][j] == board[i + 3][j + 3])
        printf("\n3");

  //checks left diagonal win
  for (i = 0; i < sizeWidth - 3; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < sizeHeight - 3; j++)
      if (board[i][j] != 0 && board[i][j] == board[i + 1][j - 1] && board[i][j] == board[i + 2][j - 2] && board[i][j] == board[i + 3][j - 3])
        printf("\n4");

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`i` is the starting column, `j` is the starting row, and you're checking 4 adjacent rows/columns. If you didn't subtract 3 from the width/height respectively you would overflow into non-existent rows/columns.

Edit:
In fact the left diagonal code is bugged and will overflow the board. Should be like this:

```
//checks left diagonal win
for(i=0;i<sizeWidth-3;i++)
    for(j=3;j<sizeHeight;j++)
        if(board[i][j] != 0 && board[i][j]==board[i+1][j-1] && board[i][j]==board[i+2][j-2] && board[i][j]==board[i+3][j-3])
            printf("\n4");
```